# Parse file and splitting individual lines into 2d array

Tags: java, file

I have one text file in which each String holds one line of numbers say 203 and I have one 2d array `int puzzle[][]`.

The lines of file are in the array list `Arraylist<String>` lines .The first String from the array list goes into puzzle[0].The second String goes into puzzle[1], etc.

The problem I'm having is that after splitting the lines I cannot convert those numbers into integers because it gives me number format exception for -1 what if I will split that - and 1 as well.

I tried the following and also making deep copy of the string array and then transforming each string into an integer

```
public void parseFile(ArrayList<String> lines)
  {

     ArrayList<String> l = lines;
     for(int i =0; i<puzzle.length; i++)
         puzzle[i][0] = Integer.parseInt(l.get(i).split(""));
 }
```

it should give me 2d array with integers

Comment: Can you provide the sample input as well?

Comment: It sounds like that file format is bad, how do you know if 203 is 2,0 and 3 or 20 and 3 for instance?

Comment: Is this part of some programming challenge?

Comment: these are the three lines in that array list with numbers like -10-1

Comment: that is why there is comment box if you don't understand anything you can ask

Comment: @AbhishekAbhishek Can you add sample input and output

Comment: -111,2-13 these are the two lines with 6 numbers output would be these numbers inside 2d integer array

Comment: Im not understand well how the lines should be putting in the Array. What should be the output with input -111,2-13 ???

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that will take a list of strings made up of single digit numbers and convert the list to a 2d array of int. This code makes no use of Java 8 streams.

```
public static int[][] parseFile(List<String> lines) {
    int[][] result = new int[lines.size()][];

    int multiplier = 1;
    int counter = 0;
    for (String line : lines) {
        List<Integer> row = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            char c = line.charAt(i);
            if (c == '-') {
                multiplier = -1;
                continue;
            } 
            int n = (int)c - 48; 
            row.add(n * multiplier);
            multiplier = 1;
        }
        int[] rowArray = new int[row.size()];
        for (int j = 0; j < row.size(); j++) {
            rowArray[j] = row.get(j);
        }
        result[counter] = rowArray;
        counter++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Below is my test code, execute from main

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("-111");
list.add("2-13");

int[][] result = parseFile(list);
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < result[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%d ", result[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Output

> -1 1 1
>   2 -1 3